Calculate value of input field based on dropdown selection
I'm trying to add 50 to the totalValue if dropdown value is true.
<div class="col">
  <label class="form-label">Emergency</label>
  <select class="form-select" name="emergency" id="emergency" [(ngModel)]="registration.emergency" (ngModelChange)="onEmergency()">
    <option value="false">No</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="totalValue" id="totalValue" [(ngModel)]="registration.totalValue" disabled>
</div>

Here's my .TS file of Angular 17:
onEmergency(){
    if(this.registration.emergency == true){
      this.registration.totalValue = Number(this.registration.totalValue) + 50;
      console.log("clicked: any");
    }
    console.log("clicked: yes");
  }

Nothing happens when I select true in the dropdown.
In the console, I see clicked: yes only.

the value is probably a string.  You might try  if(this.registration.emergency == "true") And set that property's type as string.

No. It's a boolean. It throws an error when I put it within the quotes.
When I set to if(this.registration.emergency = true), it starts to add 50 but it adds for both yes and no + keeps adding up too.

with "=" it's assigning a value.  What is the declared type of registration.emergency? The "value" attribute of your  tag is probably returning a string.  For 2nd problem, If you dont' want to add to , just change totalValue to = 50.

registration.emergency is a dropdown with just yes/no as an option. If yes, add 50. If no, add 0.
Also, totalValue can be anything and depends from user to user. If it is 500 and the other chooses yes, it should become 550.

you are binding the pulldown to registration.emergency.  (the model in some .ts file)  That should be defined somewhere.

for that +50, when the user switches back and forth between the options it'll keep adding 50.  You may not want that behavior.  Might need a function to compute totalvalue that evaluates whole model... call that when when necessary.  It may help if you include full .ts and .html file in your question.

If you console.log() your registration object your going to notice that your property emergency got converted to a string when the ngModel updated the property based on the option value.
if you check on your browser console the following expression:
'true' == true // false

you are going to see that this returns false and that's why you didn't see your expected output.
In order to make your code work, you need to use this guy -> [ngValue] binding on your option tag
<option [ngValue]="false">No</option>
<option [ngValue]="true">Yes</option>

By using it, when the ngModel updates your registration.emergency property it will actually be of a boolean type and not string and the if statemant will work as you expect.
Hope this helps!! :D
